# How to preserve YAML flow collection style for arrays when processing a YAML block with Helm's toYaml?

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm

I am inserting a YAML block from my values file into my template as shown below (Helm v3.5.2):

This is a snippet from my values.yaml:

```
data:
   values: [a, b, c]
```

This is how I include it in my template:

```
data:
{{ toYaml .Values.data | indent 3 }}
```

This is the rendered output:

```
data:
   values:
   - a
   - b
   - c
```

Is there a way to retain the notation with square brackets when using the toYaml template function?

Edit: As pointed out correctly in the comments, both notations are semantically the same. However, if I have a lot of lists with a lot of values, the notation with brackets will produce less lines.

Comment: It shouldn't matter at all; both forms are the same YAML data model and Kubernetes will read them as the same.  You could manually iterate through the list if you really needed to.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to retain. `.Values.data` is a `[]string` which holds no information at all about the way it was written in the source YAML. The information is already lost when parsing `values.yaml`, leaving you with no possibility to recreate the original style from inside the template.

It shouldn't matter though, as the output you get is semantically equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my actual values file I have a lot of arrays with a lot of values and the rendered yaml file ends up with a lot of lines. But I guess I'll have to accept that.